# Find Restaurant ID (RID) From OpenTable Using Place Name

Tags: api

I have been searching for an answer to this question and can't seem to find it - is there a way to dynamically search for Restaurant ID (RID) from opentable API using either establishment NAME or Lat/Long?

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//www.opentable.com/widget/reservation/loader?**NEED THIS CODE rid=412810 **&domain=com&type=standard&theme=standard&lang=en-US&overlay=false&iframe=true'></script>
```

Documentation on site (https://platform.opentable.com/documentation/#directory) makes it seem like you always need RID.

Answer (score 1):

check [this unofficial api](https://github.com/sosedoff/opentable)
You can get restaurants with specific parameters or get a specific restaurant only.

Good luck

```
Find restaurants

GET /api/restaurants
Parameters: (at least one required)

price - Price range for the restaurant. Values: 1-4.
name - Name of the restaurant
address - Address line. Should not contain state or city or zip.
state - State code (ex.: IL)
city - City name (ex.: Chicago)
zip - Zipcode (ex: 60601)
country - Country code (ex: US)
page - Page (default: 1)
per_page - Entries per Page, can be one of [5, 10, 15, 25, 50, 100] (default: 25)
Returns response:

{
  "count": 521,
  "per_page": 25,
  "current_page": 1,
  "restaurants": [ ... ]
}
Find a single restaurant

GET /api/restaurants/:id
Returns a single restaurant record, see reference for details. Example:

{
  "id": 107257,
  "name": "Las Tablas Colombian Steak House",
  "address": "2942 N Lincoln Ave",
  "city": "Chicago",
  "state": "IL",
  "area": "Chicago / Illinois",
  "postal_code": "60657",
  "country": "US",
  "phone": "7738712414",
  "lat": 41.935137,
  "lng": -87.662815,
  "price": 2,
  "reserve_url": "http://www.opentable.com/single.aspx?rid=107257",
  "mobile_reserve_url": "http://mobile.opentable.com/opentable/?restId=107257",
  "image_url": "https://www.opentable.com/img/restimages/107257.jpg"
}
```